# Manipulating DataFrames on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I recently failed to finish a code for a job interview. One of the problems is that I decided to use Pandas (it made sense) but I was unfamiliar with it (however I know Python Scipy and Numpy), so it took a lot of time to figure out everything. It's the first time I wrote such kind of code manipulating Pandas data frames, thus I was wondering if you could give me advice to do things better.

The purpose of the code was to read a CSV table of trading data (for a finance company) and then manipulating the data in order to find certain properties. I did not finish it, but do you think I could have done something that make it run faster? it took 43 minutes to do just what it does now. The .csv file is a 1.2GB file.

Moreover, if you have any observation about style it is more than welcome.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chunk_size = 10**5 #safe on memory
auction_division = 40000.0 #empirical
path = 'scandi.csv'

col_names = ['id','empty0','bid_price','ask_price','trade_price',\
    'bid_volume','ask_volume','trade_volume','update',\
    'empty1','date','seconds','opening','empty2','con_codes']

col_names_load = ['id','bid_price','ask_price','trade_price',\
    'trade_volume','update','date','seconds','con_codes']

start = time.time()
total=0
stocks=set()
days=set()
sub_chunks = []

for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(path, sep=',,|,',names=col_names, usecols=\
    ['id','bid_price','ask_price','date','seconds'],\
    engine='python', chunksize=chunk_size)):

    ids_unique = set(chunk.id.unique().tolist())
    day_unique = set(chunk.date.unique().tolist()) 
    stocks|=ids_unique
    days|=day_unique

    auction_data = chunk[chunk['bid_price']>chunk['ask_price']]
    new_el = auction_data[['date','seconds']]
    sub_chunks.append(new_el)


days_list = list(days)
auction = pd.concat(sub_chunks)
au_bound = []
stocky=list(stocks)

for day in days_list:
    g=auction[auction['date']==day]
    slot1=g[g['seconds']<auction_division].seconds
    slot2=g[g['seconds']>auction_division].seconds
    au_bound.append((slot1.min(),slot1.max(),slot2.min(),slot2.max()))


the_last_element = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((7, len(stocks))), columns=stocky)
#rows: 0: bid price, 1: ask price, 2: trade price, 3: trade volumes, 4: date, 5: seconds, 6: flag

for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(path, sep=',,|,', names=col_names, 
usecols = col_names_load, engine='python', chunksize=chunk_size)):
    print i+1, 'th chunk'
    #I select just trade updates because ticks and bid-ask spreads make sense at the trade (that's what I think to have learnt from investopedia)
    #Tick: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tick.asp
    #Bid-Ask Spread: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bid-askspread.asp
    chunk_clean = chunk[ chunk['update']==1 & ((chunk.con_codes=='@1') \
        | (chunk.con_codes=='XT') | (chunk.con_codes=='XT|C') | (chunk.con_codes=='XT|O') ) ]

    stocky_b = set(chunk.id.unique().tolist())

    for stock in stocky_b:
        for day, ab in zip( days, au_bound ):

            stock_chunk=chunk_clean[(chunk_clean['id']==stock) & (chunk_clean['date']==day)]

            #time between trades subtraction
            stock_chunk.loc[:,'t_b_trades']=stock_chunk['seconds']-stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1)
            #eliminate trades that cross auctions 

            stock_chunk.loc[stock_chunk[
               ( (stock_chunk['seconds'] > ab[0]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'] < ab[1]                  ) )\
             | ( (stock_chunk['seconds'] > ab[2]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'] < ab[3]                  ) )\
             | ( (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) > ab[0]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) < ab[1]) )\
             | ( (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) > ab[2]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) < ab[3]) )\
             | ( (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) < ab[0]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'] > ab[1]         ) )\
             | ( (stock_chunk['seconds'].shift(1) < ab[2]) & (stock_chunk['seconds'] > ab[3]         ) )\
              ].index.values,'t_b_trades']  = np.nan

            #the first row is always wrong
            if (the_last_element[stock][6]==1 and the_last_element[stock][4]==day):
                if stock_chunk.empty==False:
                    stock_chunk.loc[stock_chunk[stock_chunk['seconds']==stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]].index.values,'t_b_trades'] \
                            = stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]-the_last_element[stock][5]

                    #eliminate trades that cross auctions 
                    if  ( ( (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0] >ab[0] ) & (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]< ab[1])) \
                        | ( (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0] >ab[2] ) & (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]< ab[3])) \
                        | ( (the_last_element[stock][5] > ab[0] ) & (the_last_element[stock][5] < ab[1])) \
                        | ( (the_last_element[stock][5] > ab[2] ) & (the_last_element[stock][5] < ab[3])) \
                        | ( (the_last_element[stock][5] < ab[0] ) & (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]> ab[1])) \
                        | ( (the_last_element[stock][5] < ab[2] ) & (stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]> ab[3]))):

                        stock_chunk.loc[stock_chunk[stock_chunk['seconds'] == stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]].index.values,'t_b_trades'] = np.nan        
            else:
                if stock_chunk.empty==False:
                    stock_chunk.loc[stock_chunk[stock_chunk['seconds']==stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[0]].index.values,'t_b_trades'] = np.nan

        #fill the last row for the next chunk
            if stock_chunk.empty==False:
                the_last_element[stock][0]=stock_chunk.bid_price.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][1]=stock_chunk.ask_price.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][2]=stock_chunk.trade_price.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][3]=stock_chunk.trade_volume.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][4]=stock_chunk.date.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][5]=stock_chunk.seconds.iloc[-1]
                the_last_element[stock][6]=1


end = time.time()
tot_time = (end-start)/60.0
print tot_time, 'minutes for data! for', total, 'chunks of size', chunk_size
```

Here the first 3 lines of the input file

```
ID,Underlying Type,Underlying,Risk-Free Rate,Days To Expiry,Strike,Option Type,Model Type,Market Price         
0,Future,1.9119,-0.0009,19.3599,2.0264,Call,Bachelier,0.096576518   
1,Future,0.8731,-0.0025,278.2703,1.0610,Call,Bachelier,0.40362827
```

Comment: Does it work as intended? What does the input and output data look like? Can you post examples of both?

Comment: @Mast yes the code works as intended, as I said in the post. Here there is an example of the input
ID,Underlying Type,Underlying,Risk-Free Rate,Days To Expiry,Strike,Option Type,Model Type,Market Price
0,Future,1.9119,-0.0009,19.3599,2.0264,Call,Bachelier,0.096576518
1,Future,0.8731,-0.0025,278.2703,1.0610,Call,Bachelier,0.40362827

Comment: Please add it to the question itself, exactly how it's written down in your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few tips that might help you:

- Good job declaring your global variables at the top of the file. Convention is to capitalize them.
- Posting some example data here (even just a row or two) would help greatly.
- To get the unique lists of ids and days, I don't believe you need both the `.unique()` method and the `set()` functions. I believe just the `.unique()` method is sufficient and the more performant option.
- I would be surprised if you needed to call `pd.read_csv` in chunks for a 1.2 GB file. Further, I suspect this is really slowing you down.
- Many of your `for`-loops and deeply nested `if` statements you might consider refactoring into functions to improve readability and re-usability.
- The code is sparse on useful comments.

Apologies for the brevity of this response. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: ID,Underlying Type,Underlying,Risk-Free Rate,Days To Expiry,Strike,Option Type,Model Type,Market Price
0,Future,1.9119,-0.0009,19.3599,2.0264,Call,Bachelier,0.096576518
1,Future,0.8731,-0.0025,278.2703,1.0610,Call,Bachelier,0.40362827
many rows like these!